# Workbook_Open event changes other workbooks

Tags: excel, events, vba

I have the code below in Workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
        Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

But when I open the workbook in question, the settings in the code are also applied to all other workbooks that are opened. How could I limit the settings in the code to apply only to the workbook in question?
Best Regards

EDIT:
This solution does not work for me either:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Me
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, add a `With me` in the line after the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` like this

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
with me
'all the rest of the code
end with
end sub
```

it worked here

Comment: thats wierd, i had 3 workbooks open and it only changed the one i've had the macro on, you've placed the code on the workbook section?

Comment: So really dosen't make sense i tested here over and over and it's only changing the one i have to code on, i've created a new workbook placed the same code and it only changed that workbook

Comment: I agree, that is strange. My collegue also get the same behavior as I do... I added an BeforeClose workbook event to restore the settings so then the workbook is closed the other workbooks restores to their default layout.